# Spring: not accept POST request under mvc:resources? how to fix that

Tags: spring, post

I am using spring framework in my project,

Here is part of my web.xml:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>SpringMvcServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            /WEB-INF/servlet-context.xml
        </param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>SpringMvcServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<filter>
    <filter-name>httpMethodFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>httpMethodFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/system/404.html</location>
</error-page>
<error-page>
    <error-code>500</error-code>
    <location>/system/500.html</location>
</error-page>
```

And configure:

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/system/**" location="/WEB-INF/pages/system/" />
```

But I find so many error in my log, some request like this:

- POST /index.php
- POST /notexists.html

They were not exists in my server, so will call "/system/404.html", but the mvc:resources don't accept POST method, so it will return 500 Error.

How to fix that? or work around?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**First of all: I think you abuse the `ResourceHttpRequestHandler` when you try to use it for POST requests.** -- And I am not sure that every thing works correct if you made this handler to handle POST requests.

---

`<mvc:resources />` configure an instance of class `org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler`. This has the super class `WebContentGenerator` and this super class has a property `Set<String>   supportedMethods`.

So all what you need to do is:

```
<property name="supportedMethods">
    <list>
       <value>GET</value>
       <value>HEAD</value>
       <value>POST</value>
    </list>
</property>
```

Unfortunately this requires that you configure the `ResourceHttpRequestHandler` by hand instead of using `<mvc:resources />`

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping">
     <property name="urlMap">
         <map>
              <entry key="/system/**" value="myResourceHandler" />
         </map>
     </property>
     <property name="order" value="100000" />       
</bean>

<bean id="myResourceHandler" name="myResourceHandler"
      class="org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler">
      <property name="locations" value="/WEB-INF/pages/system/" />
      <property name="supportedMethods">
         <list>
            <value>GET</value>
            <value>HEAD</value>
            <value>POST</value>
         </list>
     </property>
     <!-- cacheSeconds: maybe you should set it to zero because of the posts-->
</bean>
```

*I have not proved this configuration, I have just written it down from what the `ResourceBeanDefintionParser` does.*

Comment: Thank, I will try it later. I am not use "POST", but some scaner or robots POST those requests, I just think return normal 404 is better, not return 500 error.