# SpringMVC 3 405 - Request method 'POST' not supported

Tags: spring-mvc, sitemesh

**Controller**

```
@Controller
public class Tester {
    @RequestMapping(value="testPost", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView testPost(){
      ModelAndView _mv = new ModelAndView();
      _mv.setViewName("shared/post");
      return _mv;
    }
}
```

**HTML**

```
<form action="testPost" method="post"> 
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

**Web.xml**

```
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>iCubeHRS</display-name>

   <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

   <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>        
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

   <filter>
        <filter-name>site_mesh</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.sitemesh.config.ConfigurableSiteMeshFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>site_mesh</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

   <session-config>
        <session-timeout>20</session-timeout>
    </session-config>

</web-app>
```

**Question**

Once set "method" attribute to "POST", when you hit submit button, it always turn into  405 - Request method 'POST' not supported, if delete method attribute from conotroller, and delete method="post" from HTML as well, it works, anyone know how to solve this problem?

**Update**

I think I found the problem, this issue caused by sitemesh3, after i removed sitemesh3 features from web.xml, POST works fine, but I don't know how to solve it.

Comment: so it's working with get method but not with post method?

Comment: yes, it works with get method but not with post method

Comment: what's the code in web.xml about servlet url-pattern?

Comment: Hi, please see the web.xml, I added sitemesh support

Comment: paste annotations you have on your controller class

Comment: also make sure you actually load recompiled classes and restart the server

Comment: hi soulcheck, please see the update, and I released this code to a separated tomcat, still the same problem.

Comment: could you please try to find if this only happen withen this controller, try to create another controller and test post method see if it's working...your code seems fine!!

Comment: actually I tested another function in this controller, and it doesn't work, okay, I will test another controller

Comment: so what "sitemesh" do anyway?

Comment: sitemesh is just filter for the request and response, before all the response return to client, sitemesh will intercept all the response and render the response with template decoration html file

Comment: @shore so did you find out the problem?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this is relevant to your setup but I had the same error (405-post not supported)

Initially I thought it was sitemesh related.  However when I looked into it a bit more in my case it was because I was using `<mvc:resources /`> to provide a static mapping to the decorator.

it was `<mvc:resources />` that was not accepting the post requests for the decorator file as sitemesh was trying to access it using a Post request.

I changed the mapping of my decorator file to make sure it was static and responded to POST and GET requests.  More details here [Spring: not accept POST request under mvc:resources? how to fix that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15588001/spring-not-accept-post-request-under-mvcresources-how-to-fix-that)

The code I used is

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping">
 <property name="urlMap">
     <map>
          <entry key="/DecTest/**" value="myResourceHandler" />
     </map>
 </property>
 <property name="order" value="100000" />       
</bean>

<bean id="myResourceHandler" name="myResourceHandler"
      class="org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler">
      <property name="locations" value="/DecTest/" />
      <property name="supportedMethods">
         <list>
            <value>GET</value>
            <value>HEAD</value>
            <value>POST</value>
         </list>
     </property>
     <!-- cacheSeconds: maybe you should set it to zero because of the posts-->
</bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well as you figured out that the problem was with sitemesh. [this link](https://code.google.com/p/petclinicplus/) is to a project integrating springMVC with sitemesh

Comment: Hi there, I failed to find any information from your link, would you please please paste the proper link to me again? thank you

Comment: well it is a link to a real project where it uses sitemesh and springMVC and I thought it would help to check it out in you machine you could use this link http://petclinicplus.googlecode.com/svn/ since you're not a member of this project then you will have to check it as readonly

Comment: yes, I reviewed the code, and I think the code using sitemesh2.3, but I'm using sitemesh3, I don't know whether 2.3 has the same problem, will do a testing