# Sitemesh3 POST fail

Tags: spring, sitemesh

Repost [SpringMVC 3 405 - Request method 'POST' not supported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15878935/springmvc-3-405-request-method-post-not-supported?noredirect=1#comment22656576_15878935)

**HTML**

```
<form action="testPost" method="post"> 
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

**Action(SpringMVC)**

```
@RequestMapping(value="testPost", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String testPost(){
      return "shared/post";
}
```

Before adding sitemesh3 filter, this submit action which 'post' method executed perfectly,

but once add sitemesh3 filter, if changed HTML and action both to GET, still works perfectly, however if I change to POST, the action was invoked, but returned '405 - Request method 'POST' not supported'

so I think sitemesh3 changed something when the action response to client. I reviewed the source code of sitemesh3, but didn't find any valuable things.

anyone can help? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is relevant to your setup but I had the same error (405-post not supported)

Initially I thought it was sitemesh related.  However when I looked into it a bit more in my case it was because I was using `<mvc:resources /`> to provide a static mapping to the decorator.

it was `<mvc:resources />` that was not accepting the post requests for the decorator file as sitemesh was trying to access it using a Post request.

I changed the mapping of my decorator file to make sure it was static and responded to POST and GET requests.  More details here [Spring: not accept POST request under mvc:resources? how to fix that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15588001/spring-not-accept-post-request-under-mvcresources-how-to-fix-that)

The code I used is

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping">
 <property name="urlMap">
     <map>
          <entry key="/DecTest/**" value="myResourceHandler" />
     </map>
 </property>
 <property name="order" value="100000" />       
</bean>

<bean id="myResourceHandler" name="myResourceHandler"
      class="org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler">
      <property name="locations" value="/DecTest/" />
      <property name="supportedMethods">
         <list>
            <value>GET</value>
            <value>HEAD</value>
            <value>POST</value>
         </list>
     </property>
     <!-- cacheSeconds: maybe you should set it to zero because of the posts-->
</bean>
```