# Spring boot REST controller POST request handling

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot

Using Spring Boot (v1.2.6.RELEASE), I need to accept  POST requests for the Controller methods.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/myWebApp/signup")
public class RegController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/registerFamily", method = { RequestMethod.POST  }, headers = {"Content-type=application/json"})
@ResponseBody
public FamilylResponse registerFamily(@RequestBody @Valid FamilyRequest familyRequest){
```

...
    }

When I send **POST** request from REST clients from Chrome/mozilla,the response comes as follows:

```
{"timestamp":1446008095543,"status":405,"error":"Method Not Allowed","exception":"org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException","message":"Request method 'POST' not supported","path":"/myWebApp/signup/registerFamily"}

...
```

The stack trace is as follows:

```
  org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException: Request method 'POST' not supported
at org.springframework.web.servlet.support.WebContentGenerator.checkAndPrepare(WebContentGenerator.java:273)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.support.WebContentGenerator.checkAndPrepare(WebContentGenerator.java:251)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler.handleRequest(ResourceHttpRequestHandler.java:207)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.HttpRequestHandlerAdapter.handle(HttpRequestHandlerAdapter.java:51)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
```

Following the response of [Spring: not accept POST request under mvc:resources? how to fix that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15588001/spring-not-accept-post-request-under-mvcresources-how-to-fix-that),

I think some other sub class of **WebContentGenerator**, like **WebContentInterceptor**, **RequestMappingHandlerAdapter**  should handle the requests for Controllers.

Also while running Junit tests, I found that the **RequestMappingHandlerAdapter** is handling those requests for Controllers.

But I'm yet to find how to configure this to accept POST requests as well?

Any other better solution should be more than welcome.

**EDIT**:

**Tomcat** uses **WebMvcAutoConfiguration.WebMvcAutoConfigurationAdapter**(a subclass of WebMvcConfigurerAdapter)
 and

WebMvcAutoConfiguration.WebMvcAutoConfigurationAdapter.**addResourceHandlers**(ResourceHandlerRegistry) does the following:

o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/webjars/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]

o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]

In **junit**, I have added an empty concrete child class of WebMvcConfigurerAdapter.

and WebMvcConfigurerAdapter.addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry) does nothing.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebAppContext extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {}

@Configuration
@Import({ WebAppContext.class })
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
public class ExampleApplicationContext { }


@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {ExampleApplicationContext.class})
@WebAppConfiguration
public class RegControllerTest {  ... }
```

Comment: Do you send a `Content-Type` header?

Comment: @zeroflagL, Sorry I was sending to wrong URL. So, the default /** was taken

Answer (score 7):

It's hard to say what's wrong, because your code seems fine.
But I'll try to suggest some small changes, that may help to clarify situation.

At first, you don't need additional `@ResponseBody` annotations while you are using `@RestController`. From [spring site](https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/):

> Spring 4’s new @RestController annotation, which marks the class as a
>   controller where every method returns a domain object instead of a
>   view. It’s shorthand for @Controller and @ResponseBody rolled
>   together.

Also, the problem may hiding under your `headers` requirement. If it is not specific, you can change it to `consumes` option. Try the snippet below.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/api", method = RequestMethod.POST, 
                    consumes = "application/json", produces = "application/json")
```

Comment: Updated the question.

Comment: @labbhattacharjee I see your edit, but now don't understand what are you trying to achieve. Do you want to just handle POST request in the Controller, or manage resource files by it? 
Did my suggestion about `headers` and `consumes` helped you?

Comment: @Vadyml, Thanks for your response. I don't want to handle resource files by controllers. No, I'm still getting HTTP 405

Comment: @labbhattacharjee I can suggest to try change in your code this `method = { RequestMethod.POST  }` to this `method = RequestMethod.POST`. Also remove `headers = {"Content-type=application/json"}`, if you didn't it. If this doesn't helps the problem is not in controller.

Comment: @labbhattacharjee Also you may try to add to your controller [this working sample method](http://pastebin.com/MNVB3sWk) and check how it works.

Answer (score 2):

Based on [spring doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestMapping.html#headers--), the `headers` attribute:

> The headers of the mapped request, narrowing the primary mapping. Same
>   format for any environment: a sequence of "My-Header=myValue" style
>   expressions, **with a request only mapped if each such header is found
>   to have the given value**. Expressions can be negated by using the "!="
>   operator, as in "My-Header!=myValue". "My-Header" style expressions
>   are also supported, with such headers having to be present in the
>   request (allowed to have any value). Finally, "!My-Header" style
>   expressions indicate that the specified header is not supposed to be
>   present in the request.

So, your `POST` request will be mapped correctly if and only if a `Content-type` header with `application/json` value is present. The better approach for limiting `Content-Type` would be `consumes` attribute. If you were using `consumes` attribute, in case of a invalid or missing `Content-Type` header, a `415 Unsupported Media Type` would return, which more desirable.

Comment: Updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure to check, you have @CompnentScan({ your controller base package } of Controller classes.
2. Make sure to check on application startup log
   s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/v1/accounts],methods=[POST],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[application/json],produces=[application/json],custom=[]}" onto public default T[] com.bank.dev.controller.ICrudController.create(T...)
   s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/v1/accounts/{uuid}],methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[application/json],custom=[]}" onto public default T com.bank.dev.controller.ICrudController.get(java.lang.String,java.lang.String)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This is not an answer to the question, it's a comment/new question. Once you have sufficient reputation (50) you will be able to comment on any post. In the meantime you can gain reputation by asking your own questions or providing answers on subjects you know.